# \pmatrix does not showing right

Tags: amsmath

I am typing the following code with:

```
$M =
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w \\
\end{pmatrix}$
```

However, I found the output is

[image: matrix]

and the error message from LaTeX is

> ```
> "missing value, treated as zero. 
>  <to be read again> 
>                      c
> "
> ```

I use `amsmath` package. I really do not know where is the "c" come from.

Any one would like to give me a hint to check how to fix the error?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex6} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,epsf}
 \usepackage{enumerate} 
\slugcomment{Comments} 
\shorttitle{Title} 
\shortauthors{Authors}
 \begin{document} 
$M = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \\ \end{pmatrix}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code works (in a document), so the stray `c` is some stray character. Please show the document that generates this issue.

Comment: The final `\\\` should be removed.

Comment: @Bernard: Could an `c` column specifier of the underlining array environment leak in there?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I quite agree with you, but furthermore the O.P.'s code has a spurious double backslash (she/he's not the only one to think a tabular or matrix last row must end this way).

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, quite. (But it is not the cause of the issue). Let's wait for an update

Comment: First, I want to thank you for giving promote help.

Comment: Yes, the '\\' should be removed but it does not cause the "c" problem. 

I think this problem is caused due to the template I use and I do not know how to fix it (possibly by adding or editing one package?). If you are interested, I could provide the code below:

\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex6}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,epsf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\slugcomment{Comments}
\shorttitle{Title}
\shortauthors{Authors}
\begin{document}
$M =
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
z & w \\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}